# Regenerate github pages domain name

Tags: github, github-pages

I am using github pages via organization account and it hs created a random domain name for me e.g https://effective-lamp-816e8e33.pages.github.io/

Does anyone know how we can make github regenerate this url i.e I am NOT looking for a custom domain. We are fine to use auto generated domain name but want a different name to the one thats been created now by github.

Is there a way to make github autogenerate another name for my repo ?

renaming the repo seems to be a solution but thats not something we can do unfortunately